# Is there a way to force android to accept slow charging?

Tags: charging

My impression is that since the most recent Android updates my phone is shutting off the portable charger completely after warning me about slow charging. I basically get that on anything other than the charger that came with it. Do any of you find this?

I have a number of portable chargers I carry along with me that are sort of my backups until I can get to an outlet but I'm finding I can't get them to work anymore. I've checked the portables and they are fully charged. Is my assumption wrong? If not wrong is there a way to get into the advanced settings to get Android to lighten up? :)